# What is the point of using _ in import in go

Tags: go

I have seen a strange syntax in go while importing packages: `import _ fmt`.

I am aware that `import f fmt` works like an alias for this package and also I know that `_` is used as a variable that should not be cared about.

So no prize for guessing that here I am importing a package that I am not going to use. And in fact it looks like this is what happening here.

---

What I fail to understand is **why this might be helpful**. If I use `for _, v := range(arr){}` I use `_` because I have no choice and I need to specify to the compiler that it should not worry about the variable that I will not be using.

But if I do not intend to use a package, I would just omit it (if it might be useful later, I would comment it). But no reason for it to be compiled and added to source code.

So is there any point of using this syntax, or is this just a useless artifact from combining aliasing and unused variables?

Answer (score 6):

It means that you want to import it for the side effects. It's usually used with packages that include an `init`. Of course you could import it normally, too, but the `_` makes it clear that you only wanted the side effects.

Search for "Import for side effect" in [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) for discussion.

A very common example is `net/http/pprof`, which attaches some new handlers to the default mux. Packages like `github.com/SlyMarbo/spdy` use it in the same way to silently modify the default http client.

Comment: Can you please explain what side effects can I get (apart of boosting the size of an execution file)

Comment: Usually, the side effect is something gets registered with some other library.  For example, most SQL database drivers, import for side effect and then you can use sql.Open("dbname","url")